# Example URIs for unit testing IDN domains

Tags: asp.net, unicode, dns, subdomain, idn

I am building a C# tool that does some minor manipulation on URIs. I am trying to write unit tests to makes sure the tool can support IDN domains, e.g. `例え.テスト`.

Are there any resources that can help give me some examples of IDN domains so that I can use them in my tests?

Answer (score 0):

The list of current top-level domains at http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt contains, at the time of writing, 123 live IDN domain names. All of them should have a subdomain `nic.<tld>`. I can't think of a second-level IDN name that can be relied on to exist, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The [Universal Acceptance Steering Group](https://uasg.tech/) has been working extensively on spreading awareness about Internationalized Domain Names (IDNs) and Email Address Internationalization (EAI). The group has produced a widely researched and collaboratively created document titled ""UASG 004 Use Cases for UA Readiness Evaluation EN"" with details of test domain names and email addresses for developers to use when evaluating the UA readiness of their systems. In addition to ASCII based domain names, the document lists domain names from the following scripts: Arabic, Armenian, Bengali, Chinese (Simplified, Traditional), Cyrillic, Devanagari, Ethiopic, Georgian, Greek, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Hangul, Hebrew, Hiragana, Kannada, Katakana, Lao, Latin, Malayalam, Myanmar, Oriya, Sinhala, Tamil, Telugu, Thaana, Thai and Tibetan.

Text data file corresponding to this report is available in [UASG004A](https://uasg.tech/download/uasg-004a-use-cases-for-ua-readiness-evaluation-data-en/) document.

For those who are interested in ensuring that their systems are fully compatible to IDNs and EAI, they can also go through the "[Universal Acceptance Readiness Framework - UASG026](https://uasg.tech/download/uasg-026-ua-readiness-framework-en/)".